# mypy: different error message for the same missing package

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mypy

basically, with flask_api and flask_sqlalchemy installed (via pip3), if I run mypy on this

```
import flask_sqalchemy
import flask_api
```

the error message is this

```
testMypy.py:1: error: No library stub file for module 'flask_sqlalchemy'
testMypy.py:1: note: (Stub files are from https://github.com/python/typeshed)
testMypy.py:2: error: Cannot find module named 'flask_api'
testMypy.py:2: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
```

now, I do know that as of Jan/19/2019, flask_sqlalchemy and flask_api doesn't have stub files in the typeshed (yet), but I think if both modules are installed in the system, the error messages should both be "No library stub file for module ..", what are the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two error messages mean the same thing. The only difference is that you get the first error message if the module you're importing is considered to be a "popular" third party library -- specifically, if it's one of the modules [in this list](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/moduleinfo.py#L22). In this case, `flask_sqlalchemy` is a member of that list, but `flask_api` isn't.

The reason why mypy special-cases these modules is largely for usability: it's somewhat confusing to get an error message like "Cannot find module named 'blah'" when you've seemingly installed it via pip. So, it special-cases 3rd party libraries that are likely to be commonly used so it can at least improve the user experience there.

A follow-up question you might have is "why doesn't mypy just look at what's pip-installed and use the first error message whenever you try importing *anything* that's pip-installed?". After all, mypy needs to do this anyways to try and find [PEP 561 compatible packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/) -- packages that declare they come bundled with type hints.

Well, mypy probably *could* be doing that -- but this section of the codebase was added before PEP 561 was a thing (before mypy really needed to be scanning pip-installed packages), and I suspect nobody's really thought about this corner of the codebase for a long time.

Comment: +1 for the follow up question, going in depth about the implementation detail for mypy. Now if I only I had the technical-know-how to make that fix and PR..